# fttw3 create 2D plan partially fails

Tags: fft, fftw

I have a problem with FastFourier... ( FFTW3 )

data of 100x100 samples > transformed to complex frequency domain using FFTW3
and later on I want to use the backtransform

forward plan:

```
fftw_plan fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(int n0, int n1,
                                double *in, fftw_complex *out,
                                unsigned flags);
```

The inverse looks just like this

```
fftw_plan fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d(int n0, int n1,
                                fftw_complex *in, double *out,
                                unsigned flags);
```

This is my code:

```
int ncols = 100;  // a 100x100 picture
int nrows = 100; 
int nccols = ncols/2+1;
```

// complex has to be allocated n/2+1 according to
// http://www.fftw.org/doc/Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html

```
double * Aa = (double*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(double)*ncols*nrows);
fftw_complex * Af = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*nccols*nrows);
double * Ba = (double*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(double)*ncols*nrows); 
fftw_complex * Bf = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*nccols*nrows);
double * Bc = (double*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(double)*ncols*nrows); 

fftw_plan forwardA = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(nrows,ncols,Aa,Af,FFTW_FORWARD | FFTW_ESTIMATE); 
fftw_plan backwardA = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d(nrows,ncols,Af,Aa,FFTW_BACKWARD | FFTW_ESTIMATE); 
fftw_plan forwardB = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(nrows,ncols,Ba,Bf,FFTW_FORWARD | FFTW_ESTIMATE); 
fftw_plan backwardB = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d(nrows,ncols,Bf,Bc,FFTW_BACKWARD | FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

This is exactly the same code as here: http://werner.yellowcouch.org/Papers/subimg/index.html

My problem now  is that forwardA and forwardB point to 0x0 whereas backwardA and backwardB are valid.

any idea on why this happens?

Comment: okay... I found the problem. the r2c functions only have one possible direction. So apparently the library doesn't like additional information :D SOLUTION: FTW_FORWARD as flag was not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fftw_plan forwardA = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(nrows,ncols,Aa,Af,FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

that should work.